# How to redirect directly to previous jsp page when result set is null in second jsp page in java

Tags: java, jsp

I have two jsp pages one.jsp and two.jsp.

1. In one.jsp contains table row have a link when i click that link it redirects to two.jsp page and display data.
2. My problem is two.jsp page when result set(two.jsp) is empty not display two.jsp it is directly redirect to one.jsp page with an error message

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you two.jsp if you get empty resultset you can redirect to one.jsp using following code:

```
RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher; 
requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/two.jsp");
requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: `requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/one.jsp");` when i take `one.jsp`  instead of  `two.jsp` it's working but how can i display error message in `one.jsp`